# Why does my python process stop after a few iterations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why the following code just stops functioning after a few iterations. The python process will keep running in terminal but no files get downloaded or checked.

Can someone please help? Thanks

```
#Manga downloader
#!python 3
import requests
import os
import bs4
import time
import urllib.request
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

url='http://www.mangareader.net/'
name=input("Enter comic name:")
chapterstart=int(input("Enter starting chapter number:"))
chapterend=int(input("Enter ending chapter number:"))

nameinput=name.replace(" ","-")

os.makedirs('Documents/Manga/',exist_ok=True)
directorylevel1='Documents/Manga/'+nameinput+'/'
os.makedirs(directorylevel1,exist_ok=True)

a=chapterstart

def imagesave(mangaUrl,filename,directorylevel2):
    #res = requests.get(mangaUrl)
    #print(res)
    #res.raise_for_status()
    fulldirectoryname=directorylevel2+filename
    mangapath=Path(fulldirectoryname)
    if mangapath.exists():
        print(fulldirectoryname + ' exists. Moving on.')
    else:
        print('Downloading image %s...' %(filename))
        req = urllib.request.Request(mangaUrl, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response: #open(fulldirectoryname,'wb') as outfile:
            outfile=open(fulldirectoryname,'wb')
            shutil.copyfileobj(response,outfile)
            response = None
            req = None

    #imageFile=open(fulldirectoryname,'wb')
    #for chunk in res.iter_content(10000000):
    #    print(chunk)
    #    imageFile.write(chunk)
    #imageFile.close()

#for chapter 1 to 50
def main():
    for a in range(chapterstart,chapterend+1):
        b=str(a)
        directorylevel2=directorylevel1+b+'/'
        os.makedirs(directorylevel2,exist_ok=True)
        c=str(a+1)
        url='http://www.mangareader.net/'+nameinput+'/'+b
        stopurl='http://www.mangareader.net/'+nameinput+'/'+c
        res = requests.get(url)
        res.raise_for_status
        soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        mangaElem = soup.select('#imgholder img')
        #the imgholder is the div class name then img is the image inside
        #print(url)

        #for pages 1 to end
        while url !=stopurl:

            if mangaElem == [ ]:
                print('Could not find image')
                break
            else:
                mangaUrl=mangaElem[0].get('src')
                filename=mangaElem[0].get('alt')+'.jpg'
                imagesave(mangaUrl,filename,directorylevel2)
                prevLink=soup.select('#imgholder a')[0]
                url='http://www.mangareader.net'+prevLink.get('href')
                res = requests.get(url)
                res.raise_for_status
                soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
                mangaElem = soup.select('#imgholder img')
                #soup = None

        a=a+1

    print('Done')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You mean, it downloads some of the manga and then stops in between? Try referring to this: https://github.com/GrayHats/MangaReader if you can.

Comment: No output? No line where it stops? No pre-diagnose at all?

Comment: Unrelated tip: Space after comma and between operators makes the code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing to consider:

Your code runs flat out -- that is, it keeps grabbing files at computer speed from the site.  The site expects files to be grabbed at human speed -- if it detects anything faster, it might block access after a few files.  I see that you imported `time` but didn't use it -- perhaps you meant to add a `time.sleep(1)` between accesses to prevent being locked out.

Years ago, I would occasionally be tasked with manually blocking sites from an online scientific database when accesses were happing too fast.  I know of government databases that document the access speed (pages per second) below which programs should stay to avoid being blocked.

Be a good netizen.  Worth a try.